# FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17020

Tags: ios, authentication, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What does this mean?

```
FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17020
```

I am trying to sing in as user on a FireBase app from iOS. I enabled the email authentication method on the **Firabase** console and created a user.

Here is the complete error:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17020 "Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x134fadd30 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: ->, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray - [-]>{type = immutable, count = 3, values = (
    0 : <cert(-) s: *.googleapis.com i: Google Internet Authority G2>
    1 : <cert(-) s: Google Internet Authority G2 i: GeoTrust Global CA>
    2 : <cert(-) s: GeoTrust Global CA i: Equifax Secure Certificate Authority>
)}, NSUnderlyingError=- {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: ->, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x134d7e240 [0x1a0880b68]>{type = immutable, count = 3, values = (
    0 : <cert(-) s: *.googleapis.com i: Google Internet Authority G2>
    1 : <cert(-) s: Google Internet Authority G2 i: GeoTrust Global CA>
    2 : <cert(-) s: GeoTrust Global CA i: Equifax Secure Certificate Authority>
)}}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=-, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=-, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}}, error_name=ERROR_NETWORK_REQUEST_FAILED, NSLocalizedDescription=Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.}
```

What could be the reason?

I am running this on an iOS device connected to Wi-Fi.

This is the code that generates this error (disclaimer: I took this from the Firebase examples):

```
- (IBAction)didTapEmailLogin:(id)sender {
  [self showSpinner:^{
    [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:_emailField.text
                           password:_passwordField.text
                         completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                             [self hideSpinner:^{
                               if (error) {
                                 [self showMessagePrompt:error.localizedDescription];
                                 return;
                               }
                               [[[_ref child:@"users"] child:user.uid]
                                    observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
                                           withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                                              if (![snapshot exists]) {
                                                [self promptForNewUserName:user];
                                              } else {

                                                  //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signIn"         sender:nil];
                                              }
                                            }];
                             }];
                         }];
  }];
}
```

Comment: Your authentication token might have expired. Try signing out first.

Comment: I am getting this suddenly today what could be the reason? @mm24

Answer (score 0):

Error Code: 17020 is defined Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

This means that a firewall or something blocked your connection to the Firebase servers.
In my case, I have an internal firewall and found that one of the rules broke the connection.
In your case, you can not establish a secure connection to Firebase, because I think you are behind a corporate firewall and they may apply SSL-inspection. So I advice you to open hotspot from your phone and use cellular connection.